# Maximize $f(x) = x^3-3x$ subject to constraints

Tags: analysis, optimization

I would like to understand more about how to maximise functions of one variable subject to constraints.

How can you find the maximum value of $f(x) = x^3 - 3x$ subject to $x^4+36 \leq 13x^2$?

The answer is apparently $f(x) = 18$ at $x=3$, but if this is true, how can you derive it without a computer?

Comment: Do you know how to take a derivative?

Comment: @RossMillikan  Yes. It is the constraint I don't know how to handle.

Comment: The derivative won't help here. The values that give zero violate the constraint.

Comment: @user69810: The derivative *does* help, because without computing the derivative (or something similar), you don't know if there are any critical points in the feasible region.

Comment: @Hurkyl This is a simple function. $x^{3}$ dominates $3x$ for values of $x>1$. Thus, to maximize this function you take the farthest value to the right which is allowed. In this case that is $x = 3$.

Comment: @user69810: There's not much difference between knowing that $f(x)$ is increasing on $x>1$ and knowing that $x=1$ is a critical point of $f$. And going through the full calculation helps us avoid silly mistakes in our shortcuts like overlooking the fact that $f(0) > f(1.5)$ or $f(-1) > f(1.9)$, had the feasible region been different.

Comment: @Hurkyl As my statics professor used to say, "Alright, you win. Take the marbles and go". :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extreme value for a differentiable function can either come at a point where the derivative is zero or at the end of the interval of definition.  You can take the derivative, getting $f'(x)=3x^2-3$ and find it is zero at $x = \pm 1$, then check those points and find $f(-1)=2, f(1)=-2$.  Unfortunately, as we will see, these violate the constraint.  Then you need to check the ends of the interval of definition.  To have $x^4+36 \le 13x^2$ we need $(x-3)(x-2)(x+2)(x+3) \le 0$ so the function is defined on $[2,3]$ and $[-3,-2]$  You need to evaluate $f(x)$ at those four endpoints and take the greatest.

Comment: Thanks. That's very clear. Just on a formal note, is this fact about differentiable functions taking extreme values either where the derivative is zero or at the end of the interval of definition stated in a known theorem?  The extreme value theorem seems not to cover it exactly unless I am misreading it.

Comment: @motl737:  I don't find a name for it.  There is a discussion [here](http://education.ti.com/html/t3_free_courses/calculus84_online/mod13/mod13_lesson2.html) but it doesn't give a name.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $x^4 - 13x^2 + 36 = (x^2 - 9)(x^2 - 4)$

Use this and the fact extrema for continuous functions defined on a closed interval occur at critical points or on the boundary of the interval

Answer (score 0):

So the difficult part is the constrain:
 
$x^4-13x^2+36\leq0\iff(x^2-4)(x^2-9)\leq0\iff(x-2)(x+2)(x-3)(x+3)\leq0\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this.

The first part would be to rearrange the constraint equation to be $x^4-13x^2+36 \leq 0$. By using derivitves, we can find the zeroes of this function, and they occur at $x = \pm 2$ and $x = \pm 3$. Also by using derivatives, we can find the function is decreasing on the intervals $(-\infty, -\sqrt{\frac{13}{2}})$ and $(0, \sqrt{\frac{13}{2}})$ and increasing on the intervals $(-\sqrt{\frac{13}{2}},0)$ and $(\sqrt{\frac{13}{2}},\infty)$. Thus we know that the function satisfies the constraint on the intervals $[-3,-2]$ and $[2,3]$.

The second part is simply finding the maximum values of the function on these intervals, which you can do with derivatives, which you stated you know how to calculate. See [here](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~hjlai/Words2Algebra/MinMax_Closed_Interva.pdf) if you don't already know how to do this.